# Copy one Xml Document contents into another one in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to copy contents of one xml file into another xml file. I found many examples where copying nodes is done but could not find how to just copy all the content.

Is this possible at all? If so can you please provide some direction.

Thanks

Edit:
I want to create this new xml file in the location dynamically supplied by the application's text box.

Thanks again.

Comment: What do you mean by "copy contents of one xml file into another..."?  Is the expected output an exact clone of the original file, or are you doing some kind of mapping or transformation?

Comment: I think I am looking looking for File.Copy(). I was over thinking in terms of nodes and all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to replace one XML file with another, why not use `File.Copy`?

Comment: Never thought of it that way.. Thanks. I will try this.

Answer (score 3):

As a file:

```
string sourcefile = "somefile.xml";
string destinationfile = "anotherFile.xml";
System.IO.File.Copy(sourcefile, destinationfile);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `File.Copy()` what you're looking for?